# Certification failure on Outlook AddIn - Terms of Use

Tags: office-store

I am submitting an update to a previously accepted Outlook Addin. I got a certification failure from my submission stating:

**100.5.1.4 Terms of Use**

*Microsoft default or boilerplate Terms of Use may not be used. Please update the Terms of Use to use conditions specific to the add-in and resubmit your offer.*

Unfortunately, I can not find anywhere in the dashboard where I can submit a link to our terms of Use for the AddIn. Can anyone provide some information about how I should handle this situation?

Best
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

On the properties tab in your Partner Center account, if you scroll to the bottom of the page you will see a field called 'End User License Agreement (EULA) link'. It should be entered there.

Comment: So it's in the EULA link. I was confused because the rejection message mentioned TOU, not EULA.